# Is it correct to use the scores of PC1 as a composite index?

Tags: r, pca

I have three correlated variables for 18 cases. I would like to construct a composite index using PCA, where each case has a score. Basically to reduce three dimensions to one, and use that dimension to construct an index that presents most of the variability of the original data.

Here are some of the results:

```
$scores
              PC1        PC2         PC3
 [1,] -2.66448394  0.5090662  0.07754897
 [2,]  0.91439302  0.1847204 -0.60893752
 [3,] -2.22683755  0.3331123 -0.35014666
 [4,] -1.79669198 -0.3613678  0.52445128
 [5,] -0.16855445 -1.2628732 -0.13261310
 [6,] -0.85153118  0.8867761 -0.20803321
 [7,]  1.06141195 -0.6518869  0.22136818
 [8,]  2.53454368  0.5642474  0.46476647
 [9,] -0.06048957 -0.5559017 -0.30619004
[10,]  1.11297744 -0.4881618  0.00379941
[11,]  1.09216692 -0.5246241 -0.18362310
[12,] -0.32933949 -0.7235955  0.73342404
[13,]  1.17148303 -0.2045210 -0.28475936
[14,]  1.44147655  1.8556052  0.26550696
[15,]  1.40530566  0.4048750 -0.22613411
[16,]  0.78226781 -0.4538815 -0.08510098
[17,] -2.46168023  0.1684606 -0.10541561
[18,] -0.95641766  0.3199502  0.20008838

$loadings
          PC1        PC2        PC3
V1 -0.6055294  0.3894576 -0.6940151
V2 -0.5086870 -0.8600761 -0.0388151
V3 -0.6120226  0.3295328  0.7189134

$sdev
[1] 1.5335819 0.7272552 0.3452919

$totdev
[1] 3
```

**Summary**

```
Importance of components:
                            [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
Standard deviation     1.5335819 0.7272552 0.34529185
Proportion of Variance 0.7839578 0.1763000 0.03974215
Cumulative Proportion  0.7839578 0.9602578 1.00000000
```

**Eigen values**

```
$values
[1] 2.3518735 0.5289001 0.1192265

$vectors
          [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] 0.6055294  0.3894576  0.6940151
[2,] 0.5086870 -0.8600761  0.0388151
[3,] 0.6120226  0.3295328 -0.7189134
```

If I stay with just PC1, how do I know the composite index score for each of the 18 cases?

Does the PC score itself provide the composite index value for each case?

Do I have to sum the product of the first eigenvector values and the original data for each case? I.e. to compute (0.6055294*Original data V1)+(0.5086870*Original data V2)+(0.6120226*Original data V3).

Or, is there other way to calculate the composite index for each of the 18 cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does the PC score itself provide the composite index value for each case?

Yes, this is correct. You just take the scores of PC1 and that's it.

This is exactly what PC1 *is*: it is a composite variable (linear combination of the original three variables) that has the maximal possible variance.

> Do I have to sum the product of the first eigenvector values and the original data for each case?

You can also do that. This is exactly how PC1 scores are computed. You will get the same result.

Comment: Many thanks @amoeba !
If I may, could you suggest a way to normalize the pc scores so that they are more comprehensible to the audience/readers. Besides max =1, min=0

Comment: Why do you think that it is not comprehensible without normalization?

Comment: I really don't have a answer for that, so maybe I'll just left the results like that! 
Again, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$loadings
          PC1        PC2        PC3
V1 -0.6055294  0.3894576 -0.6940151
V2 -0.5086870 -0.8600761 -0.0388151
V3 -0.6120226  0.3295328  0.7189134
```

That means:

```
V1 = -0.6055294*PC1 + 0.3894576*PC2 -0.6940151*PC3
V2 = -0.5086870*PC1 - 0.8600761*PC2 -0.0388151*PC3
...
```

If you want only use PC1 then just truncate the formulae:

```
V1 = -0.6055294*PC1 
V2 = -0.5086870*PC1 
...
```

which is then the "best" prognose such that the error ***over all*** V-items is the smallest if you want only use one predicator.

Comment: Any chance you could elaborate a bit on the linear algebra and thought behind the steps that you're describing? That would be great if you had the time.

Comment: @Antoni: Well, that is just the *convention* write the result of the PCA in the table form: The compositions of $V_1$ by $l_{1,1} \cdot pc_1 + l_{1,2} \cdot pc_2 + l_{1,3} \cdot pc_3$ and analoguously for $V_2$ and $V_3$ in the shorter /matrix-style type which you also showed in your question. *How* that solution is derived using linear algebra is surely well explained in wikipedia and surely also here in SSE, so please kindly save me that labour ...

Comment: @Gottfried, I think the question was not about how to reconstruct original variables using only PC1; the question was what values to use to reduce the dimensionality to 1. The answer to this is of course to use PC1 without any further multiplications.

Comment: @amoeba: Ok, I'm a bit tired - perhaps I misunderstood things. Likely better to delete the whole answer...

Comment: Don't delete, just extend it when you have some time! What you wrote is useful too.